# Moving Demo Site to Live Site - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost

It's my first time to move a whole site into another folder.

I have created my new wordpress site in my localhost using WAMP then transferred it into my new folder 
which is

```
www.mysite.com/new/
```

**Problem 1**: The theme admin panel has a lot of broken images, when i checked the URL. its like

```
http://localhost/mynewsite/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/image.png
```

It should be like

```
http://mysite/new/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/image.png
```

There are like hundreds of images/icons that are broken..

Here's the process i have made when i transferred the new site to the new folder.

1. Download / upload  database
2. upload all files into the /new folder
3. configured the wp-config and connected it to the new database

**Problem 2**: Even thou the theme admin panel has a lot of broken images, i continued to populate content and even upload images, i did set a bunch of absolute URL's like

```
 http://mysite/new/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/image.png
```

Now the Question is: When i transfer the NEW site and overwrite the old one. How can i change the Absolute URL's w/o changing them one by one? I mean is there a way to just remove the new/ in all content and databases?

Comment: when doing this i usually export the entire db to a .sql file, load into a text editor with search/replace functionality and update all absolute urls, then import to the server db.

Comment: Oh i ddnt know that! Ill check that

Comment: thanks flauntster! this worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

With wordpress you need to amend your siteurl and home in your database as well - this can be done by phpmyadmin or you can add this to your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.mysite.com/new/');                   
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.mysite.com/new/');
```

Take a look at: [Edit wp.config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) and [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)